# iPhone screen recording without red bar suddenly appeared on my phone

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-capture

This morning I woke up to a notification on my iPhone saying that the current screen recording session was stored to my camera roll. I didn't do any screen recordings lately (definitely not last night).

There was indeed a new recorded session in my camera role of about 17 seconds, dated to 4:56am this morning (I usually get up at around 5, but definitely didn't touch the phone prior to seeing the message).

In the recording, "someone" swiped down on my (apparently unlocked!) home screen (it is locked at night and is in airplane mode, just like last night), entered "mys" in the search bar, waited, deleted it, entered "dyn", waited, exited back to the home screen and then the recording stops. You can even see the airplane mode icon, meaning there was no remote connection possible. I recognize the home screen as my own in its current configuration.

Now what's bugging me: Let's assume I was sleep drunk and just can't remember doing all the above. The recording doesn't show the red bar it usually shows on my iPhone (SE) when recording sessions (I double checked right after). So even if someone should have sifted through my phone and accidentally turned on screen recording, the red bar should have been visible in the recorded session.

I'm on iOS 11.4.

I'm really lost here. I can't even see how someone should be able to pull off a prank on me, as there wasn't any internet connection available or anything. The phone is not jailbroken and never was. I bought it vanilla from Apple. I never noticed any other odd behavior on that device.

I appreciate any kinds of thoughts on this. I'm in a mixed state of curiosity, anxiety and confusion.

Comment: Any evidence somebody entered your room without your notice? Do you have a history of sleepwalking?

Comment: No, no evidence that anyone got near my phone besides myself. Also, no sleepwalking or schizophrenia on record to date.

Comment: Are you sure the red bar is actually visible in other recordings?  Sometimes screen capture software automatically omits itself from the recording (like webex screen sharing doesn’t include the webex window in what is shared).

Comment: @Wildcard At least in iOS 12, it does. Also only an unlocked phone screen can be recorded. I start it from a shortcut in control centre.

Comment: Are you the only one who's face is in FaceID in Settings? Or you don't have any FaceID? Do you have a password? Are you the only one to know it?